# images have the same format: some images show up, others dont

Tags: html, image, src

i am trying to add images to my webpage, and im using the img tag:

for some reason, the image doesn't load. I have more images under the same directory, and when i replace the image name with some other image, it shows up in the web page. This means that some images are able to load and some images are not able to load for some reason. The images are all the same format. Why do some images show up and others don't if they have the same format?

Does anyone know what is the reason for this?

Comment: What image formats are you using?

Comment: this is happen if there is difference in the name like demo.png and Demo.png are different even demo.png and demo.PNG are different so this might be happened with you

Answer (score 0):

Open your images in a photo editor software like photoshop, and check the `Mode` of your images. It must be `RGB`, not `CMYK` or something else.

in photoshop you can do this from `Image/Mode/RGB Color` menu.

But before check your file names and case sensitivity of them.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're case is related to **case sensivity**. Probably you have your image name or it extension in upper-case for some characters.
Check if your `img-src` tag has the exact name and extension of that image.